# Saving an .xls file to .xlsx reduces its file size by 500mb, is this caused by compression?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a .xls file with PivotTables that is 500mb large, and when I convert it to an .xlsx format, it drops to a mere 5mb. Even after clicking Data>Refresh All which refreshes the PivotCaches, the file size remains small. The same size reduction occurs if I save as .xlsm or .xlsb.

Microsoft's documentation states that XML format and ZIP container is much more memory efficient than binary documents. I have no reason to believe data loss or corruption occurred as functionality remains the same, is compression a plausible explanation for such a drastic (90%) reduction in file size? Is there a way to actually test that the file size reduction was caused by the compression?

Thank you.

Comment: idle curiosity: have you tried ZIPing the `XLS` file? If yes, how big is the resulting ZIP archive?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad the resulting ZIP archive is 50mb

Answer (score 2):

.xlsx files, like all their post-2007 Office cousins such as .docx, .pptx etc are zip containers.

You can change the extension to .zip and take a look at the contents of the file and folder structure (more interesting for documents with media in such as PowerPoint files with images). If you unzip to a folder you should be able to see the relative sizes.

I would not be at all surprised to find 90% compression ratio in many spreadsheets, as there is a lot of repetition with similar formulae etc. I seem to remember reading an article a long time ago (when these formats were relatively new) about the way Excel stores bits of formulae to give compression the best chance of big file size savings.

Comment: While it is reasonable to assume that zipping XML will achieve a high compression ratio, .xls files are not XML.

Comment: Yes, XLS is based on BIFF (Binary Interchange File Format) and as such, the information is directly stored to a binary format. On the other hand, XLSX is based on the Office Open XML format, a file format that was derived from XML. The information in an XLSX file is stored in a text file that uses XML to define all its parameters. Based on [Open XML Formats and file name extensions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/open-xml-formats-and-file-name-extensions-5200d93c-3449-4380-8e11-31ef14555b18), files are automatically compressed and can be up to 75 percent smaller in some cases.